# using match for both linked collection of mongo in lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections - `orders`, `feedback`

Orders:

```
{
    "restaurantId" : NumberInt(138), 
    "referenceNo" : "1980DBF5", 
    "orderId" : "1045593", 
    "userId" : NumberInt(6664960), 
    "userEmail" : "user@g.com", 
    "firstName" : "User"
}
```

Feedbacks:

```
{
    "rating" : NumberInt(4), 
    "additionalComments" : "it is working", 
    "referenceNo" : "7D02097F", 
    "productId" : NumberInt(1), 
    "restaurantId" : NumberInt(138), 
    "orderType" : "1"
}
```

I need to make a join on these two collections.

Also, there will be filter inputs on rating, referenceNo, userEmail, firstName. 
How can I use match to get data from two collections?

This is my aggregate query:

```
[
    {
   "$lookup":
     {
       "from": "orders",
       "localField": "referenceNo",
       "foreignField": "referenceNo",
       "as": "data"
     }

    }
]
```

I am using this query on `feedback` model.

The data that I get is:

```
{
        "rating" : NumberInt(4), 
        "additionalComments" : "it is working", 
        "referenceNo" : "7D02097F", 
        "productId" : NumberInt(1), 
        "restaurantId" : NumberInt(138), 
        "orderType" : "1"
        "data": [{
        "restaurantId" : NumberInt(138), 
        "referenceNo" : "1980DBF5", 
        "orderId" : "1045593", 
        "userId" : NumberInt(6664960), 
        "userEmail" : "user@g.com", 
        "firstName" : "User"
    }]
    }
```

Also, would it be possible to add limits here?
Earlier I was using this on `orders` -

```
mQuery.skip(Number(paginate.offset)).limit(Number(paginate.limit));
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if this helps....

```
db.feedbacks.aggregate([ {
     $lookup:                                          
        {
        from: "users",
        localField: "whatever",
        foreignField: "whatever",
        as: "data"                                       
    }},
{
  $unwind: "$data"
},
{
    $match:
         {
        "data.orderId":"1045593"}      //conditions
         },
{   
        $limit:1                       //limit
}
 ]);
```

Comment: The result from lookup is something like this - data[0][userEmail]. 
And this match doesn't work.

Comment: Updated the answer with a tested query.